Why does the reply address mismatch during 'get access on behlf of a user' using Microsoft Graph API?
The python code snippet requesting access is :
url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+tenant+'/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    header={}
    header['Content-Type']='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    data={}
    data['client_id']=client_id
    data['scope']='User.Read'
    data['code']=code
    data['redirect_uri']='https://localhost/myapp/'
    data['grant_type']='authorization_code'
    data['client_secret']=client_secret
    
    
    x=requests.post(url,headers=header,data=data)
    print(x.text)
    x=x.json()
    #print(x)
    tok=x['access_token']
    url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
    header={}
    header['Authorization']:'Bearer '+tok
    data={}
    x=requests.get(url,headers=header,data=data)

However the x.text value contains https://localhost/myapp/' does not match the reply address 'http://localhost/myapp/' provided when requesting Authorization code.
The traceback error shows :
tok=x['access_token']
KeyError: 'access_token'

The x responds with a 400 code and even though redirect_uri value is same the error seems wierd. ANy solutions or suggestions what could be done differently?
